# Clang AST Interpretation

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I am trying to interpret parts of the Clang AST you can see in the picture below. In short I am trying to do is to check if two variables are the same at different program points. After inspecting the AST, I noticed that the only commonality between the AST sections are the sections circled in blue.

Can anyone help me as to what these hex numbers correspond to in the AST?
I understand that the first block corresponds to a Variable Declaration and the second block corresponds to a Expression. Are there methods on Stmt and Expr classes which can be invoked to get hold of these hex numbers?

[image]

Comment: Pointer addresses

Comment: @FrankC. Thanks for that, would it be possible to extract pointer addresses from Clang AST?

Comment: Accessing clang's AST documentation covers the API, you may want to go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are indeed raw pointer values.

You most likely need to check `DeclRefExpr` nodes and their corresponding declarations that they reference (i.e. `getDecl` method). Pointer to its declaration is the hex number you are looking for.

Happy hacking with Clang!